# Weird behaviour of `not` operator with python list

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

When I'm trying to check whether a list is empty or not using python's `not` operator it is behaving in a weird manner.

I tried using the `not` operator with a list to check whether it is empty or not.

```
>>> a = []
>>> not (a)
True
>>> not (a) == True
True
>>> not (a) == False
True
>>> True == False
False
```

The expected output for `not (a) == False` should be False.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`==` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `not`. `not (a) == False` is parsed as `not (a == False)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is working as expected. Parenthesis added below to clarify how this is being executed:

```
not (a == True)
# True
not (a == False)
# True
```

An empty list, `a = []`, [*evaluates* to `False`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) in boolean expressions, but it does not *equal* `False` or `True`. Your expressions in the middle are testing whether it is equal to `False` or `True`, so they both evaluate to `False`, and `not False` is `True`.

You can add parenthesis like below to get what you expect:

```
(not a) == True
# True
(not a) == False
# False
```

Comment: For completeness sake: you can cast to bool to force a Boolean evaluation. `bool([])` returns `False`. So: `bool(a) == False` and even `bool(a) is False` are both `True`.